# Get application Id in XML dynamically

Tags: android

I'm using shortcuts in my application and I have multiple product flavors. I want to get the application Id dynamically for target package.

I've given `${applicationId}`, but it's not working. I tried with `${packageName}` didn't work. any other alternative?

```
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_barcode_icon"
    android:shortcutId="bar_code"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcuts_my_bar_code">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW.myBarCode"
        android:targetClass="com.appemirates.clubapparel.home.HomeActivity"
        android:targetPackage="${applicationId}" />
</shortcut>
```

Answer (score 6):

Manifest placeholders like `${applicationId}` are only supported for the manifest, not arbitrary other XML files, such as shortcut metadata resources.

You could try:

- Have a copy of your shortcut XML in each product flavor's source set, where that copy has the hardcoded application ID
- Use `resValue` in Gradle to set up a string resource with the application ID (per flavor), and use `@string/...` notation to refer to it in the shortcut XML

The first one definitely works but is tedious due to the code duplication. I have not tried the second one.

Otherwise, you would be looking at building your own Gradle plugin or similar processor that could dynamically generate these resources from a template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm surprised it's such a pain to create static shortcuts :/

Comment: Using the second method I get an `ActivityNotFoundException` because the string in the XML file is actually the number reference to the string: `android:targetPackage="@ref/0x7f1100a0"`. I see that the string is correctly added to the app's resources, and that the number in the error message is the correct ID of that string (but not the value as expected): 
`I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x1000c000 cmp=@2131820704/com.example.app.MainActivity bnds=[304,1690][1074,1886] (has extras)} from uid 10619`

Comment: @RoySolberg, did you solved it? i have same prob with you atm

Comment: @programmerdreamer I see that I went for the first way mentioned above; two different `shortcuts.xml` - one for each flavor.

Answer (score 4):

In your app's build.gradle.kts (Gradle Kotlin DSL) you could add:

```
android {
  // your setup...
  
  androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant ->
      variant.resValues.put(
        variant.makeResValueKey("string", "app_id"),
        ResValue(variant.applicationId.get())
    }
  }
}
```

Which will write a string into the resources with the name `app_id` and use the application ID of the variant. You will then be able to reference the string resource using `@string/app_id` inside your XML resource files. `${applicationId}` unfortunately only works in Manifest files, as has been mentioned in the other answers.

This solution should also work with flavours and build types which augment the application ID by using `applicationIdSuffix`, and thus answers the comment from [Get application Id in XML dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074999/get-application-id-in-xml-dynamically#comment126407480_57075713).

Answer (score 3):

you can create BuildConfig parameter through gradle.
You need to add below in specific build flavor

```
resValue "string", "APP_ID", "com.example.myapp.india"
```

that will generate string resource as per your build flavor.And you can directly use it as below in your code.

```
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_barcode_icon"
    android:shortcutId="bar_code"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcuts_my_bar_code">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW.myBarCode"
        android:targetClass="com.appemirates.clubapparel.home.HomeActivity"
        android:targetPackage="@string/APP_ID" />
</shortcut>
```

Let me know for more help :)

Comment: Hi ! What if I have an app with 2 flavors AND debug suffix (so 4 different appIds) ? Can I update the string into debug gradle section ?

Comment: @Guildem I have just added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204249/1795559) which also solves your problem.